# Is there a way to read data from the shadowroot using selenium webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

```css
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\******\Downloads\geckodriver.exe', options=options)
#driver.get('http://google.com/')
url =  "https://www.foxnews.com/sports/nfl-great-frank-gore-says-hall-of-famer-numbers-speak-themselves"
driver.get(url)
item = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div.article-comments').shadowRoot.querySelector('ul.spcv_messages-list')")
print(item.text)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
```

NOTE : I'm trying to scrape fox news comments : https://www.foxnews.com/sports/nfl-great-frank-gore-says-hall-of-famer-numbers-speak-themselves. Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script.

```
import time

....

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
item = driver.execute_script('''
    let divs =  document.querySelector('div.article-comments').querySelectorAll('div');
    let shadowroot = null;
    for (el of divs) {
        if (el.hasAttribute('data-spot-im-shadow-host')) {
            shadowroot = el.shadowRoot;
        }
    }

    return shadowroot.querySelector('ul.spcv_messages-list');
''')
```

In you case, `div.article-comments` does not have `shadowRoot` attribute, you need to select specific element that holds it. In this case it will be `div` that has attribute `data-spot-im-shadow-host`.

Comment: Hi sharmiko, thank you for your response but still it is returning null. so i tried to change let shadowroot = 0 then it was still returning none

Comment: I think sometimes it needs time to load all content. I added 5 second sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.text`, use `get_attribute('textContent')`, which will retrieve data without scrolling.